# Call a function directly from the command line

Tags: vim

Is there any way to 'register' a function so that it can be called directly from the command-line, for example:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#user-commands

Comment: `:command Hello call Hello()` and now just `:Hello`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+define+command+call+function

Comment: @phd -- yes, thank you for that.